# not sure about TCP/UDP on video & normal chat app

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, video-streaming

I'm making a video chat app using python Tkinter. it will have seperate "rooms" (like Zoom for example). I've only done the video & audio part, but not the chat part.
I did it using TCP protocol and not UDP, but I recently found out that video streaming should be in UDP.

I have a few questions:

- is it *that* bad making a video chat app with TCP protocol? if not, what are the reasons?
- I know that TCP is more recommended for normal chat (text messages) but if I'm changing the video stream to UDP, do I need a new (TCP) socket for the normal chat?
- using TCP is working pretty well for now, and even a bit easier(?) because I can easily send specific data to specific clients (by just saving the client sockets). the problem is when making a NEW room. the server gets 2 times more packets, therefore it sends each client whatever he needs to get a lot slower. will it get solved by changing to UDP? if not, is there any idea on how to fix that?
- if I stay on TCP, making the text chat will be a lot easier. is that a good enough reason to make a "video chat app" using TCP protocol?

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

TCP connection is definitely more reliable as it uses three way hand-shake. Therefore, it is also slower compared to UDP. UDP also has a less packet size. For video or audio chat, the realtime aspect is more important than  having to receive all the data in ordered manner. That is what UDP was invented for.

Nowadays with faster internet speed TCP can be used for both purposes. Its fine, but may cause some lags due to slower connection.

UDP isn't recommended for chat app as it does not ensure the message will deliver intact. Use TCP for both chat and video chat as it will ensure integrity and will simplify your code.

https://images.app.goo.gl/DQ5PHSveKQNfu5VPA

Comment: so, in order to make a video chat WITH a normal chat, do I need 2 sockets in both client & server?

UDP for video/audio, and TCP for normal chat

Comment: Nowadays with faster internet speed TCP can be used for both purposes.. Its fine, but may cause some lags due to slower connection.

Comment: One `socket` will do both. But if you want to send file, then you created another `socket`.